# Monitorar uso da bateria no próprio aplicativo

Tags: android

Tem alguma forma de colocar uma funcionalidade no app, para que ele exiba o quanto ele esta gastando de bateria/energia?
Isso seria nele mesmo, e evitando que a pessoa vá para aquela config do aparelho que exibe isso, mas não sei como começar. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como começar?

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível saber o quanto um app está gastando de bateria/energia<sup>(1)</sup>.
No entanto é possível saber qual é o nível actual da bateria:

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
```

se a bateria está a ser carregada ou não:

```
int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING;
boolean isCharged = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
```

Veja na documentação como [Monitorar alterações no estado de carregamento](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#MonitorChargeState) e [Monitorar alterações significativas no nível da bateria](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#MonitorLevel).

Referências

- [Monitoramento do nível de energia e do estado de carregamento.](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#MonitorLevel)

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> Não é possível saber programaticamente mas é possível usar o [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) para despejar os dados colectados do uso da bateria para o pc e criar um relatório que pode ser analisado usando o [Battery Historian.](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/battery-historian.html)</sub>

Comment: Então, eu cheguei a dar uma lida sobre, mas não era exatamente o que eu estava precisando, mas agradeço :)